# Please ensure that you refer to Figure 3 in your text as, if accepted, production will need this reference to link the reader to the figure

Tags: journals, journal-workflow

I have submitted revisions to a journal. The editor asked that:

> 1. Please ensure that you refer to Figure 3 in your text as, if accepted, production will need this reference to link the reader to the figure.
> 2. Please ensure that you refer to Table 9 in your text as, if accepted, production will need this reference to link the reader to the Table.

What does the editor mean? The article contains 17 table and three figures, but he only raised issue with figure 3 and table 9.

Figure 3 and table 9 have been mentioned in the text already.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question does not concern academia, but rather it is a problem that you have to deal with by yourself.

Comment: I don't understand why the editor refers to production. Surely "the reader will need this reference to link between the text and the figure/table" is more relevant?

Comment: @user2768 I assume they want to produce hyperlinks for each table / figure.

Comment: @user2768 "production" means a person, also known as a copyeditor.  The editor is saying they are making this request because they know the copyeditor will want it.

Comment: @padawan Why is this a problem that the OP has to deal with themselves? Why can't we help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can't be generalized to other situations.  You should ask the editor, not the internet.

Comment: Disagree with close votes, this can be useful to others.

Comment: Is it perhaps a technical thing, such as using LaTeX and not having a "\ref" reference to the figure, and instead writing "figure 3" as text?

Answer (score 15):

Did you mention the other figures and tables in your text? Usually, you should have a sentence like "as shown in fig. 3" or "in table 9, we see..." for each and every table and figure.

Maybe the editor just gave examples - you should do it for all of them.

**Edit** to incorporate the comment into the answer:

It might be a misunderstanding. Since you should address all reviewer's / editor's comments, you should write something like "*fig. 3 and table 9 are mentioned on p.x line y. If this is not sufficient, I did not understand your remark, please elaborate on this issue*"

Comment: yes i have explicitly mentioned all the tables and figures

Comment: Then it might be a misunderstanding. Since you should address all reviewer's / editor's comments, you should write something like "fig. 3 and table 9 are mentioned on p.x line y. If this is not sufficient, I did not understand your remark, please elaborate on this issue"

Comment: thanks for your valuable comments, i am considering to contact the editor for clarification